# How do I allocate an array of vectors?

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to follow the code posted by a user on Stack Exchange and I'm having trouble with an allocation of a matrix.  The code is:

```
dim = 3;
XX = Table[X[[i]], {i, dim}];
```

and it's supposed to create an array of:

```
{X[[1]], X[[2]], X[[3]]}
```

And it does, but I get the following warnings:

```
Part::partd: Part specification X[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
Part::partd: Part specification X[[2]] is longer than depth of object. >>
Part::partd: Part specification X[[3]] is longer than depth of object. >>
General::stop: Further output of Part::partd will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

What's the proper way to allocate this matrix without the warnings?

Comment: If `X` has no parts, you can not use `Part` on it.

Comment: In Mathematica there is almost never a need to pre-allocate an array. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure for what you are going to use this for, but I use things like `XX = Table[X[[i]], {i, dim}];` frequently for symbolic preprocessing code for `Compile`. In that case, `Array[X, dim]` won't work.

You can ignore the warning with `XX = Quiet[Table[X[[i]], {i, dim}]];` or you can use `XX = Table[Indexed[X,i], {i, dim}];` instead.

As I found out only recently, `Compile` is clever enough to substitute `Indexed` by `Part` as can be seen in the following example:

```
dim = 3;
XX = Table[Indexed[X, i], {i, dim}];
cDf = With[{code = D[Sin[XX[[1]]] + XX[[2]]^3, {XX, 1}]},
   Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}}, code, CompilationTarget -> "C"]
   ];
CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[cDf]
```

Comment: That's a useful trick (the `Indexed`). I never knew that one.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yeah, me neither. =D

Comment: Stumbled over your post @HenrikSchumacher and tried your neat example on MM9. Unfortunately, the `CompilePrint[]` gives me `MainEvaluate[]` calls, which are not supposed to be there in your example I guess. When I use compile and need to pre-allocate an array, I create a zero-array. However, it's not symbolic then. I am just currently looking for the fastest way to do this (currently I simply call `Table[]` within compile).

Comment: @DisplayName The trick about `Indexed` is pretty new and won't work in older version (version 9 is actually not that fresh any more). You might want to try the undocumented ``Compile`GetElement`` instead of `Indexed` (will also be quite a bit fast if also the option `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` is added). Or you can use the good old `Part` instead of `Indexed` and neglect the `Part::partd` messages by wrapping everything with `Quiet`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Ok, that explains it. Yeah, you actually taught me to use ``Compile`GetElement``, since then I stick to this one. This is a undocumented function, right? Where do you learn these kind of things? Is there a list somewhere? When using `Compile[]` you always need to pre-allocate your arrays right, there is no way to circumvent that if I use a iteration to fill e.g. a vector within `Compile`, is there? Just asking because of @Szabolcs comment further up on this page.

Comment: @DisplayName Towards Szabolcs comment: It depends. If you can build the array directly with `Table` or by linear algebra operations, you don't have to preallocate. But some algorithms require an interative scheme to build the matrix, so sometimes, yes, preallocation is necessary.

Comment: @DisplayName And I learned these undocumented things on this site. E.g., [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805) is very, very useful.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Yes, this is what I meant pre-allocation is necessary if I have an iteration involved. Ok, so at least when it comes to this I am not wasting computation time. I just wonder by whom the information on undocumented functions was spread for the first time and for what purpose there are undocumented functions at all. But thank you for the link I will certainly take a look at it!

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
dim = 3;
Array[X, dim]
```