# Taking a Part of a Part of a Variable

Tags: list-manipulation, indexed-variable

Say I have `Part` of a variable `x`.

```
Part[x, 1]
```

Then, I'll get an error message, as the variable `x` is not recognised as a list with multiple parts.

If I want to suppress this error, because I know for sure `x` will have multiple parts, I can use the `Quiet` function.

```
Quiet[Part[x, 1], {Part::partd}]
```

But now imagine that the list variable `x` itself is an element of another list `y` such that `x=y[[1]]`.

```
Quiet[Part[Part[y, 1], 1], {Part::partd}]
```

I expect this to return `y[[1][[1]]`, however, what I get is `y`.

Any ideas why this happens? Obviously the examples are simplified working examples, but it should work. How can I get my expected behaviour?

Comment: A robust way would be to use `Indexed` instead of `Part`. See also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181251).

Comment: You get `y` because `Part[y, 1]` doesn't evaluate if `y` is atomic. So the outer `Part` then extracts the first argument of `Part[y,1]`, which is `y`. This is because `Part` works on arbitrary expression, not just `List`s

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Ah, that makes sense. Though adding an `Evaluate` around the inner `Part` doesn't seem to work. The `Indexed` solution is much nicer anyway, as it also doesn't require the `Quiet`.

Comment: `Evaluate` will not do anything here since there's no hold attribute to override (see also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180500/43522) . Mathematica tries to evaluate `Part[y, 1]`, but since there's nothing it can evaluate to, it stays the way it is. That's how Mathematica handles most ill-defined expressions: it's part of the symbolic nature of the language. Mathematica uses a term-rewriting style of evaluation and when there's no applicable rules available, things just stay the way they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Henrik Schumacher's comment (feel free to answer yourself, then you'll get the credits).

A robust way would be to use Indexed instead of Part. See also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181237/how-do-i-allocate-an-array-of-vectors/181251#181251).

Example code:

```
Indexed[x, 1] 
" returns x_1 "
Indexed[Indexed[y, 1], 1]
" returns y_1_1 "
Indexed[Indexed[{{a, b}, {d, c}}, 1], 1]
" returns a "
myFunction[y_, i_, j_]:=Indexed[Indexed[y, i], j]
myFunction[{{a, b}, {d, c}}, 2, 1] 
" returns d "
```